# Hard drives do not want to go to sleep/standby automatically on Ubuntu 16.04 server with LXD/LXC 2.0

Tags: suspend, lxc, standby, hdparm

I have small server with five drives put in following layout:

*Physical drives*

```
/dev/sda (SSD EVO 850)
/dev/sdb (HDD TOSHIBA DT01ACA300)
/dev/sdc (HDD TOSHIBA DT01ACA300)
/dev/sdd (HDD WD1502FAEX-007BA0)
/dev/sde (HDD WD1502FAEX-007BA0)
```

*Logical drives*

```
/dev/sda1 (ext4) - Operating system '/'
/dev/md0 (ext4 - raid1 made of /dev/sdb1 and sdc1) - Data1
/dev/md1 (ext4 - raid1 made of /dev/sdd1 and sde1) - Data2
```

Business requirement is following:

- Most used data stays on the SSD drive so it can be active/idle all the time
- Least active occasionally accessed data are put the HDD drives and therefore the drive should be put to sleep after some time of inactivity (lets say 5 minutes)

**The issue I am dealing with is, that even if I set the drive power management explicitly, none of the drives go to sleep/standby.**

Commands I use on this (and also on other systems):

```
DRIVE_TO_SET=/dev/sdb #in general any drive I want to set PM
hdparm -B 1 $DRIVE_TO_SET
hdparm -S 60  $DRIVE_TO_SET
```

What is weird is that if I put the drive on sleep manually by:

```
DRIVE_TO_SET=/dev/sdb #in general any drive I want to set PM
hdparm -Y $DRIVE_TO_SET
```

it stays sleeping for days until anyone requests data access on it.

As far as I know there is no application periodically accessing drives preventing them to sleep. I believe the fact that they can sleep when manually put to sleep also proves there is no sleep preventing app running.

What I believe is worth of mention that the server runs all services in LXD/LXC 2.0x containers. They however keeps their images on the SSD drive using the RAID drives only to store large less used data.

The question is:

**How (what else) should I investigate to find out why the drives do not want to go to sleep?**

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the gui tool ("Laufwerke" in german maybe "disks" in english)  from the `gnome-disk-utility` could do the change which `hdparm -S` could not. You have to select the device in the ui and than type <kbd>E</kbd> in the keyboard, a scheduling window will appear where you can set up the timeout... I did the changes for each device of the raid.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not worked.